# What's the inspiration and/or meaning behind the names Dahj and Soji?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

Certainly they are reminiscent of the name [Lal](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lal), which means "loved one" in, I believe, some South Asian languages...

But what do we know here, both in and out of universe?

Comment: Apparently the words (in Sanskrit) mean "Dowry" and "Buckwheat" which isn't much help. Soji's surname (Asher) means "hope" so there may still be some connection.

Comment: @Valorum I believe the Dowry is dahej which is pronounced a bit differently.

Comment: Also the way Dahj is said sounds like how a non native speaker would say धज (dhaj) which means sun. (This is just my opinion though)

Comment: @KaranShishoo - Either way, not nearly as obvious a match as Lal

Answer (score 1):

Well, Soji means, "phraseology," "wording," or "diction" in Japanese. Very similar to "Data," "Codex," etc.

Not sure about Dahj, but I imagine it's something similar.